# How do I delete a result in mysql where the number of matching entries is below a certail number

Tags: mysql

I have the following query

```
select date, count(*) from table where date='2018-12-15' group by time having count(*) <241;
```

Which results in

```
+------------+----------+----------+
| date       | time     | count(*) |
+------------+----------+----------+
| 2018-12-15 | 00:05:00 |      116 |
| 2018-12-15 | 01:00:00 |      116 |
| 2018-12-15 | 06:45:00 |      125 |
| 2018-12-15 | 07:30:00 |      125 |
| 2018-12-15 | 08:00:00 |      125 |
| 2018-12-15 | 08:30:00 |      116 |
| 2018-12-15 | 12:20:00 |      125 |
| 2018-12-15 | 13:30:00 |      116 |
| 2018-12-15 | 21:00:00 |      116 |
| 2018-12-15 | 22:20:00 |      116 |
+------------+----------+----------+
```

I want to delete all these results. I tried the following but it isn't working :

```
delete from table where date='2018-12-15' group by time having count(*) <241;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a join within the DELETE statement:

```
DELETE a FROM table a
JOIN 
(
  select time from table where date='2018-12-15' group by time having count(*) <241
) b ON a.time = b.time
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

`DELETE FROM table
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, (
  SELECT ids_to_delete
  FROM (
     SELECT group_concat(id) AS ids_to_delete
     FROM table
     WHERE date='2018-12-15'
     GROUP BY time
     HAVING count() < 241
   ) t
))`

Comment: thanks, but I get the error "| Error | 1260 | Row 263 was cut by GROUP_CONCAT() |" (I also added the * to (*)